# how to reach to a variable in another js file in appcelerator alloy

Tags: variables, appcelerator, onload, titanium-alloy

I have a small problem.

I have index.js

```
var loc = require('location');
function doClick (){
loc.doIt();
}
```

in location.js I have these

```
var dee  = 12;
exports.doIt = function() {
    alert(dee);
};
```

Which means that when I click on the button I can get the alert, however, I want to reach these information without a need of click - onLoad - besides I want to return two values not only one.
How I can fix this maybe it has really an easy solution but because I have been working for a while my mind stopped working :)

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move your location.js to inside app/lib (as module). for example :

```
// app/lib/helper.js
exports.callAlert = function(text) {
   alert('hello'+ text);
}
```

and then call it in your controller like this :

```
var helper = require("helper"); // call helper without path and .js extension
helper.callAlert('Titanium');
```

and your problem should be solved :)